# why cmd just print command and dosen't work?

Tags: vb.net, ffmpeg

I tried create a website that could upload mp4 then my server would transcode it to ts and create a m3u8 playlist。
    I wanted to use cmd to control ffmpeg to do this，and I use visual basic to do this.

Here is my code：

```vb
  Dim fileName As String = "borderoflife"
  Dim file As String = "borderoflife.mp4"
  Dim appPath As String = "C:\allen0916\"
  Dim saveDir As String = "test2\"

  Dim savePath As String = appPath & saveDir
  Dim saveResult As String = savePath & file

  Dim Content_Type_A As String = "video/mp4"

  Dim m3u8Path As String = Path.Combine(savePath, fileName + ".m3u8")
  Dim para As String = String.Format("/C ffmpeg -i {0} -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -s 640x360 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls {1} ", saveResult, m3u8Path)

  Dim output As String = "none" 
  Dim p As Process = New Process()

  p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
  p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False 
  p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True 
  p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True 
  p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True 
  p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True 
  p.Start()
  p.StandardInput.WriteLine(para) 
  p.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit")
  p.StandardInput.AutoFlush = True
  p.StandardInput.Close() 
  output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() 
  p.WaitForExit()
  p.Close()

 If System.IO.File.Exists(m3u8Path) <> True Then
      context.Response.Write(output)
  Else
      context.Response.Write("Success")
  End If
```

and every time output just returns ：

```
Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.17763.737]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. 

c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>/C ffmpeg -i C:\allen0916\test2\borderoflife.mp4 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -s 640x360 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls C:\allen0916\test2\borderoflife.m3u8 

c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>exit
```

it seems cmd.exe just print my command and not working，
Dose somebody know why？

Comment: I don't think you need the `/C` in front of `ffmpeg`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried commend without ```/c ```, it still dosen't work.

Comment: Try writing a newline to the StandardInput before the exit command.

Comment: `p.StartInfo.Arguments = para`. Remove `p.StandardInput.WriteLine(para)`, `p.StandardInput.Close()` and `p.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit")`. Don't redirect `stdOut` and `stdError` if you're not handling these. Use `Path.Combine()` to build paths (considering you're on a web site side, apparently).